# jQuery Dialogs wont stay in container div when opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm working with code to open multiple dialogs in a cascading fashion in a desktop type environment. The issue is keeping the dialogs from opening outside the container "#desktop" div. I have tried the containment option, using positioning option with at: and within: with no luck. I can set the draggable option div to #desktop and it stays in the div correctly. I have a fiddle setup for testing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jahmekyat/QGHf6/). Here is my code so far:

```
var dialogOffset = {
    top: 10,
    left: 200
};
$('button').click(function () {
    var parent = $('#desktop');
    var parentPos = parent.offset();
    var parentIndex = $('#desktop').index(parent);
    var numDialogs = $('.dlg' + parentIndex).length;
    var dialogTop = parentPos.top + dialogOffset.top + numDialogs * 30;
    var dialogPosition = [parentPos.left + dialogOffset.left + numDialogs * 30, dialogTop];

    $('<div class="dlg' + parentIndex + '"></div>').dialog({
        position: dialogPosition,
        width: 250,
        close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine when I run it. The dialogs are staying insite the div id="desktop" when I run it in chrome and firefox. What browser do you use?

Comment: If you open multiple windows, as they cascade down when opened, at about the tenth dialog window, they start to open outside of the div. If it was working the way I want it to, when it reached the bottom of the div, they would stop there and move to the right as they kept opening. Keep opening the windows until they reach the bottom of the jsfiddle frame and they should start moving to the right when they reach the bottom of the frame. Thanks for your help.